# LINQ to SQL select all fields in a table but with a distinct column

Tags: linq-to-sql

I need to return a list of counties, but I need to filter out duplicate phone code values.  For some reason I'm having trouble with the syntax.  Can anyone show me how to do this?  Should I be using the group by instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group by would work if you need the actual entity.

```
var query = db.Counties.GroupBy( c => new { c.CountyName, c.PhoneCode } )
                       .Select( g => g.FirstOrDefault() );
```

Or if you are constructing it for a view model and only need the data, you could use Distinct.  The following creates an anonymous type that could be used to populate the model.

```
var query = db.Counties.Select( c => new { c.CountyName, c.PhoneCode } )
                       .Distinct();
```

Comment: Great, the first one did exactly what I was needing, but it's good to know about the second option as well.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: I needed to obtain a complete entity while performing a distinct operation on one of the entity's columns. The first option worked perfect.